# Add dismiss job option for ads on activity page

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, activity-tab

We have a cross button on ads (while going through posts) which says "dismiss the job" and also works as feedback to remove this job from my sight:

[image]

Can I have the same for ads on my Activity page?

[image]